# how to implement a double click?

Tags: algorithm, touch, double-click

Let me explain what we are doing:
We have designed a frame of ir sensors/receivers that can be put around a screen, and basically it converts the screen into a touch-less screen. We are able to move the mouse cursor around when the user moves his finger inside the frame and we can also generate a right click, simply by seeing that if the user is holding his/her finger over the same coords for x amount of time then generate a right click.

The problem is double click. With a regular mouse a user simply double clicks the button and done. Any thoughts on how this can be achieved?

Thank you.

Comment: Why is this tagged genetic-algorithm?

Comment: You want to find a gesture that represents the double click? What inputs do you have? Single `(x,y)`? `(x,y)` for each finger? Can you detect when the user sticks out his tongue (then you can make funny YouTube videos of users double clicking)?

Comment: sorry about the genetic-algo, didn't have proper sleep it looked like generic algo?? sorry again. @BlackBear double touch as in?

Comment: just as @assaf suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution would be to use different timers for Right click and double click. When you place the finger over a clickable element, a circular progress bar appears at the position of the finger, when the progress reachs the end (the circle is complete) and the user moves the finger away a right click is detected. If the user doesn't move away the finger, a different progress bar appears, if that progress bar reachs 100%, then you have a double click.

In my opinion, a much better solution would be to **NOT** need a double click, or even a right click, check the XBox Kinect menu navigation interface for a good example.

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: we are actually controlling the mouse and we are using windows operating system, so people might wanna open a folder for which i think double click would be required. But i like the idea of timing right click and double click.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to figure out if the finger is within the screen at all; once you've got a mechanism that tells you that - you can check for this sequence:  
Time 0: (finger off screen) 
Time 1: (finger touches P1)
Time 2: (finger off screen)
Time 3: (finger touches P2)

where P1 and P2 are close (up to a preset tolerance level) and Time 3 and Time 1 are close (up to a preset double-click sensitivity level).

Comment: hmm...this sounds interesting. But the hardware gives the x,y coords. Its like breaking a beam in the x direction and another in y direction.

Comment: @rashid I think X and Y in this answer mean two points (coordinate pairs). So it's like tapping on the screen twice.

Comment: ah, gotcha! I'll try this and let you guys know the outcome. Thank you so much so far.

Comment: @biziclop correctly assessed my intention - I changed the variable names to P1 and P2 to be clear.